How to get the firebase app hosting static ip address with custom domains?
I'm having a hard time discovering the IP address of my Firebase app frontend, which is hosted with Firebase App-Hosting and uses custom domains. Does anyone know how I can find it?
For context, I need the static IP address to whitelist access to the database. We are using Next.js server-side components to perform queries directly to the database.

Firebase Hosting? Or Firebase App Hosting? They are not the same product and the difference may matter here as Firebase Hosting serves content on Fastly, while Firebase App Hosting serves it all from Google Cloud Run.

Thanks Frank! Edited it.
Exactly. It must have configured some IP for the container on Cloud Run, right? or I need to create a NAT gateway?

Firebase App Hosting serves your Next.js routes from Google Cloud Run, which by default uses a dynamic IP address pool. You can configure it to use a static outbound IP address.

Awesome, thanks Frank!

By chance, do you know how do I configure my Firebase app-hosting container VPC network and subnet range? My guess it needs to be deployed on the same NAT network every time, correct?
